# React Axios return 404 fakejson.com

Tags: reactjs, axios

Good morning,

I am following a youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfP8o2OqnLA&list=PLmYBIzXGbEzLhBgbGa7ucqGJr5RgmzjWr&index=33&t=2s

This tutorial talks about React route settings with axios and uses fakejson for data.

My code is the same but I have a 404 error.

I have done some research but I can't find anything on my side.
Need help please.
Thanks in advance.

My code Profile.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht2Qk.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Profile extends Component {
    
    state = {
        data: {}
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(this.props.match.params.profileId);
        
        const data = this.props.match.params.profileId;
        
        // code de fakejson
        let payload = {
          token: "eDoyh9fUtJ5_-PU1PT4vPw",
          data: {
            name: "nameFirst",
            email: "internetEmail",
            phone: "phoneHome",
            _repeat: 10,
          },
        };

        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "https://app.fakejson.com/q",
          data: payload
        }).then(resp => {
            
            // console.log(resp.data[data]);
            this.setState({
              data: resp.data[data]
            });
        });
        
        
        
    }
    
    render() {

    
        const { email, name, phone } = this.state.data;
        
        return(
            <div className="container mt-3">
                <h1>Profile</h1>
                <hr />
                
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li className="list-group-item"> <strong>Nom: </strong>{name} </li>
                    <li className="list-group-item"> <strong>Email: </strong> {email}</li>
                    <li className="list-group-item"> <strong>Tél: </strong>{phone} </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        
        )
    }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: what happens when you  console.log(resp.data[data]) ??

Comment: POST https://app.fakejson.com/q 404

Comment: try to console.log(resp.data) and tell me what u get

Comment: Good morning,

I tested the console log this morning and my setstate works today! Maybe a problem with fakejson yesterday! But thanks for your help!